# what method I must use Instead of findViewById in app widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

When I use `findViewById()` I get an error.
What method should I use, instead of `findViewById()` in my app widget?

P.S.: I want to do something like:

```
 Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

in my screen widget

Comment: there is no such method, which is analog to `findViewById`. RemoteViews work another way. You can't manipulate them directly.

Comment: Can you please describe what kind of error you are getting, so it will be convenient to give solution.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need a findViewById() in Widget just do this

create a static variable, which will be your onClick name tag:

```
private static final String MyOnClick = "Button OnClick";
```

Set this onClick tag to your view as below:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
views.setTextViewText(R.id.your_button, "Button Name");
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.your_button, MyOnClick);
```

get Button Click listener like bellow

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

if (MyOnClick.equals(intent.getAction())){
    //your onClick action is here
  }
};
```

Here total code

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static final String SYNC_CLICKED    = "automaticWidgetSyncButtonClick";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName watchWidget;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.sync_button, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SYNC_CLICKED));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if (SYNC_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

            RemoteViews remoteViews;
            ComponentName watchWidget;

            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);

            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.sync_button, "TESTING");

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);

        }
    }

    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
        intent.setAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is to be In OnCreate?

Comment: And what is this loop:
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }

Comment: Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)

Comment: Error:(96, 2) error: reached end of file while parsing

Comment: and Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: can you pass your xml files and activitys

Comment: points to the block, which belong to protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action)

Comment: :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Comment: please check [Widget example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_widgets.htm). Mabe it will help you

Answer (score -1):

`appWidgetProvider` class does not allow `findViewById()`. You need to use a function of `RemoteView` Class for this purpose.

[CharSequence Method | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setCharSequence(int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

in your case:

```
remoteViews.setCharSequence(R.id.button,String MethodName(onClick),String Value);
```

it works for EditText,TextView,TextClock.
You can replace `String MethodName` with the name of method like getText,setText,setTimeZone etc.
For Buttons RemoteViews offer the following function

[setOnClickResponse | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews#setOnClickResponse(int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews.RemoteResponse))

this is the equivalent of

```
View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)
```

Similarly a lot of other methods are available now such as `setFloat()`, `setLong()` which work same as `setCharSequence()`.

you can choose between them based on the datatype of parameters you want to pass.

here is the link to understand and view the list of all RemoteView functions

[RemoteViews | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews)